# 'parameters' option in the postgis_geojson.php script

Tags: php, postgis

I'm using this script (update https://gist.github.com/3763701) and it works nicely (congrats to the author), but the 'parameters' option doesn't work with my tables, for instance this call:

```
http://localhost/postgis_geojson.php?geotable=seafloor_thermometry_point_wgs84&geomfield=geom&parameters=source='GEOMAR'
```

gives:

```
There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed.
Document contents:
<br /> <b>Warning</b>: pg_query() [<a href='function.pg-query'>function.pg-query</a>]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near &quot;GEOMAR&quot; at character 110 in <b>/var/www/html/postgis_geojson.php</b> on line <b>85</b><br /> An SQL error occured.
```

however, in postgis this call:

```
select id,fid,source from seafloor_thermometry_point_wgs84 where source='GEOMAR';
```

gives:

```
 id | fid | source
----+-----+--------
  1 |   1 | GEOMAR
  2 |   2 | GEOMAR
  3 |   3 | GEOMAR
  4 |   4 | GEOMAR
...etc
```

where could the problem be?

thanks for any hint about this,

Gery

EDIT:

my postgis table has PK in id, I'm using postgis 1.5, postgresql 8.4.8, php-5.1.6-27.el5, php-pgsql-5.1.6-27.el5, apache 2 (httpd-2.2.3-43.el5) and Firefox 6.0.2 in rhel5 32-bits,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

On line 70, try changing pg_escape_string($parameters) to just $parameters